# Python3: require sudo to start a file [Eventually with ArgParse]

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

Is there a way to "require" sudo privileges to start a file in python3?
I have an ArgParse Argument which needs Sudo privileges, but it won't ask at the start of the file, instead when the command which needs it gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

Already figured out my answer now by comparing uid:

```
import sys
if uid != 0:
    sys.exit("Gib Root!")
else:
    co.printout("JA! ROOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOT \n", RED)
```

The program now checks if the active uid is 0 and if it isn't, it will exit the script.

Comment: Don't mind the funny output, it was just for some experiments.